# How to use post method in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

when I want to redirect in my page to other I use this method exception:

```
    throw new RedirectToUrlException("/login/j_security_check?j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + pass);
```

problem is that this information are visible in browser. How I can send this and use POST method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST redirects are a somewhat esoteric edge case with most browsers. Wicket's RedirectRequestHandler currently only supports HTTP codes 301 and 302. POST redirect would require 307, which will also show a warning to the user.

That said, what you are trying to do is inherently unsafe. Do *not* ever send a password back to the client.

Long story short: Wicket doesn't support this, and you shouldn't be doing this anyway.

Comment: so how should I do this ? There must be some options how to do this in other way but I dont know it

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do. What is the purpose of that redirect? To me this looks like it needs to be redesigned.