# Apache Wicket redirect POST data to external website

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

I have a apache wicket form where the contents of the form should be sent to other external website. Is that possible in wicket, If possible, please post some code. I tried with new RedirectPage(url); . But, its sending a GET request instead of POST.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954498/how-to-use-post-method-in-wicket ?

Answer (score 2):

Override getActionUrl() on your wicket form to return the url you need to submit to.

Answer (score 1):

Java code:

```
Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("myform") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected String getActionUrl() {
        return "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
}

add(form);
```

Html code:

```
<form wicket:id="myform">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```